# Could someone help me to understand the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm for discrete Markov Chains?

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

Since no answer was given at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430266/could-someone-help-me-to-understand-the-metropolis-hasting-algorithm-for-discret), I am going to make it here.

**Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm**

Assume the Markov chain is in some state $X_{n} = i$. Let $\textbf{H}$ be the transition matrix for any irreducible Markov chain on the state space. We generate $X_{n+1}$ via the following algorithm:

(a) Choose a proposal state $j$ according to the probability distribution in the $i$-th row of $\textbf{H}$.

(b) Compute the acceptance probability $\alpha_{ij} = \min\left\{1,\displaystyle\frac{\pi_{j}H_{ji}}{\pi_{i}H_{ij}}\right\}$

(c) Generate a uniform random number $U\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. If $U<\alpha_{ij}$, accept the move and set $X_{n+1} = j$. Otherwise, reject the move and keep $X_{n+1} = X_{n}$.

**MY DOUBTS**

I know that Markov chains that are aperiodic and irreducible admit a stationary distribution. I also know that any distribution $\pi$ satisfying the reversibility condition is an equilibrium distribution.

As far as I have understood, the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm proposes a Markov chain whose stationary distribution is $\pi$ (the target distribution we are interested in sampling) and then simulate the Markov chain.

**EDIT**

However, I am a little bit lost as to the interpretation of the algorithm itself. Could someone interpret it step by step to me?

I know such question is quite naive, but I am not able to understand it properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do the symbols $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j$ stand for?

Comment: I think it is related to the stationary distribution $\pi$ from which we want to sample.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit that into the body of the question.

Comment: @user1337 Can you let me know how to improve my answer or, if it is satisfactory, accept it?

Comment: @Ian Can you tell me how do we propose a candidate for the next stage through $\textbf{H}$? How do we utilize $\pi$ in order to do so?

Comment: @user1337 At that stage you do not use $\pi$ at all. You just generate $j$ by sampling from the discrete distribution with probabilities $p_j=H_{ij}$ (where $i$ is fixed equal to the current state). The target distribution $\pi$ only comes into play in deciding whether to accept the move or not. (That said, if you want to see a good convergence rate, you will choose $H$ with some idea of what $\pi$ looks like in mind.)

Comment: @Ian which method can we use to sample the transition from $i$ to $j$ based on the probability $p_{j} = \textbf{H}_{ij}$?

Comment: @user1337 Any method for sampling from discrete distributions. In practice this is often tailored to the particular problem you have, because many problems where MH is useful have an extremely large number of states.

Comment: @user1337 (Cont.) But if you have a problem which doesn't have too many states, you can use the usual probability integral transformation by choosing an ordering for the states, thus allowing you to define a CDF. In this case you are left to devise an algorithm to find the smallest element which exceeds a given number in a sorted array, which can be done directly using binary search. There are faster general purpose methods that rely on some preprocessing, such as the alias method.

Comment: @Ian Once again, thank you for the response. I still have one question, though. How the draws are related to the distribution of $\pi$? Do we consider the number of draws related to each state and normalize them by the total of iterations?

Comment: @user1337 In the limit as the number of samples goes to infinity, the number of times that state $i$ is seen divided by the total number of samples will converge to $\pi_i$. However, people typically remove some initial string of samples from consideration (the "burn-in" period) and then only draw one sample per some relatively large number of total samples (to avoid strong correlations between neighboring samples). In the limit this isn't necessary, but it helps in practice.

Comment: Dear @Ian, thank you very much for your contributions. I am now able to understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mathematical content of Metropolis-Hastings follows by examining what its transition probability matrix effectively is, even though this transition probability matrix isn't actually used to run Monte Carlo with it. This matrix has off-diagonal elements $p_{ij}=\min \left \{ H_{ij},\frac{\pi_j H_{ji}}{\pi_i} \right \}$ (you just multiply $H_{ij}$ by the acceptance probability since you make the move proposal and the move acceptance check independently). Now calculate $\pi_i p_{ij}=\min \left \{ \pi_i H_{ij},\pi_j H_{ji} \right \}=\pi_j p_{ji}$. Thus the MH transition probability matrix is reversible with respect to $\pi$, so it has $\pi$ as its unique stationary distribution.

Regarding the acceptance process, I can tell you that generally speaking, higher acceptance rates contribute to higher convergence rates. But the higher the acceptance rate is, the closer you were to "being done before you started", i.e. the closer you were to having $H_{ij}=\pi_j$. So there is a tradeoff going on here. Importance sampling for computing expected values has something very similar: the lowest possible variance is to sample with probability proportional to $x p(x)$, but the normalization constant of this distribution is already the expected value you wanted to find.

When $H$ is symmetric, the expression for $\alpha_{ij}$ simplifies somewhat; the algorithm is sometimes called the Metropolis algorithm in this context. But if $\pi$ takes on wildly varying values, then this can cause low acceptance rates and thus slow convergence, so it isn't necessarily an advantage.

One of the advantages of MH is that it does not require us to know $\pi$, but only to know $\frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}$. This is often helpful, especially in chains with many states, where we may know $\pi_i=\frac{q_i}{\sum q_i}$ but we don't know $\sum q_i$. In this situation we can still compute the ratio, because the normalization constants cancel out. A common example is when $\pi$ is the Boltzmann distribution for some energy function at some given temperature. In this situation you can define $q_i=e^{-\frac{E(i)}{k_B T}}$ and so $\frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}=e^{\frac{E(i)-E(j)}{k_B T}}$.

Regarding your edit, MH as an algorithm says: given a way to simulate from an irreducible* chain $H$, a way to compute $\pi_j/\pi_i$, and a way to generate Bernoulli random variables, you can sample from the chain with $p_{ij}=\min \left \{ H_{ij},\frac{\pi_j H_{ji}}{\pi_i} \right \}$. You do that as follows:

- Propose a candidate for the next state $j$ through $H$
- Calculate $\alpha_{ij}=p_{ij}/H_{ij}$
- Generate a Bernoulli($\alpha_{ij}$) random variable and use its result to decide whether to accept the move. This makes it so that the overall probability of a move from $i$ to $j$ is $p_{ij}$.

*Remark: $H$ does not need to be aperiodic, but the MH process itself will always be aperiodic.